# Chrome identity api to get profile info

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want general profile information of user like birthdate, gender, username,etc. I am able to get email and unique profile id of user by using `getProfileUserInfo` method of identity api. 
It returns only email and id like this:

```
userinfo Object {email: "hxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", id: "1xxxxxxxxxxx49189xx"}
```

How do I get additional information?

Comment: `chrome.identity` seems to be used for authentication purposes, not for whatever it is you want to do with personal info

Comment: So how do I get users other information? So far, I have authToken and unique userID.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although I am not sure about birthday, but you can get user's information like `id`, `name`, `given_name`, `family_name`, `link`, `picture`, `gender` , `locale`.

Code:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
    interactive: true
}, function(token) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
    }
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + token);
    x.onload = function() {
        alert(x.response);
    };
    x.send();
});
```

Just make sure you add the `url` under `scopes` in `manifest.json`:

```
"oauth2": {
        "client_id": "XXXXX",
        "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
        ]   
    }
```

Comment: Awesome! This should be enough for now. Thanks